# Why does this html element has only 1 key according to js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm reading the book road to react.

A `List` (react component) function returns this element:

```
<Item key = {item.objectID} item = {item}/>
```

`Item` is again another react component, which is defined as

```
function Item(props){
  const keys = Object.keys(props);
  console.log("properties of Item Element:" + keys)
  return(
    <li>
    <span>
      <a href={props.item.url}>{props.item.title}:</a>
    </span>
    <span style={authorStyle}>  {props.item.author},</span>
    <span> {props.item.num_comments},</span>
    <span> {props.item.points}.</span>
    </li>
  )
   
};
```

The strangest thing to me is that I would expect `props` to have two properties: `key` and `item`. However, the console only shows:

> properties of Item Element:item

Why is this?

Edit:
When I do console.log("props:" + props), I get

> props:[object Object]

Comment: could you write `console.log(props)`?

Comment: key prop is reserved prop, rename it to use in your component https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: @StepUp I've just added that information to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that that HTML element has only one key. `Item` or `props` are not HTML elements. I think your question is what happens to the `key` prop and why this prop is not accessible in your `Item` component.

While most props on a JSX element are passed on to the component, there are two special props (`ref` and `key`) which are used by React and not forwarded to components.

In your case `props.key` is `undefined`. Think of `key`s as something that's not for you to use. It's for React itself to help identify which items have changed, are added, or removed. They don't get passed to your components.

If you also want to use the `item.objectID`, you'll need to pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name.

Comment: Oh... I think I get it now. By the way, what's your opinion on the book "Road to React"? Despite the excellent reviews on Amazon, I find the book a bit lacking. It's skips many details which are important, I think.